# Creating and using BASH array of logical values

Tags: arrays, bash

As an exercise, I was trying to "optimize" the code presented for a bash-based **[game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579778/tictactoe-bash-script/75609455#75609455)**.  Unfortunately, I am having issues because I can't seem to build a **bash array of boolean values** (if/test results) then use those in a subsequent complex logic expression.

I thought I could assign values in this manner:

```
bmap[0]="dummy"
bmap[1]=$( test ${board[1]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[2]=$( test ${board[2]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[3]=$( test ${board[3]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[4]=$( test ${board[4]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[5]=$( test ${board[5]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[6]=$( test ${board[6]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[7]=$( test ${board[7]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[8]=$( test ${board[8]} == ${symbol} )
bmap[9]=$( test ${board[9]} == ${symbol} )
```

then use those in this manner

```
if \
    [[ ${bmap[1]} && ${bmap[2]} && ${bmap[3]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[4]} && ${bmap[5]} && ${bmap[6]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[7]} && ${bmap[8]} && ${bmap[9]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[1]} && ${bmap[4]} && ${bmap[7]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[2]} && ${bmap[5]} && ${bmap[8]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[3]} && ${bmap[6]} && ${bmap[9]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[1]} && ${bmap[5]} && ${bmap[9]} ]] ||
    [[ ${bmap[3]} && ${bmap[5]} && ${bmap[7]} ]]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

But the error I am getting is

```
./test_175.sh: line 29: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 30: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 31: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 32: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 33: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 34: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 35: test: ==: unary operator expected
./test_175.sh: line 36: test: ==: unary operator expected
```

Is there any way to reuse the **bmap array** values **directly as boolean operation results**, and **not** being forced to perform another test referencing those values?

Comment: `$()` is for substituting the output of a command into the command line. `test` doesn't produce any output, the result is in its exit status.

Comment: The error message may be due to missing quotes on your variable expansions.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common problems in shell code, including missing quotes.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new or modified shell code.  The reports include links to detailed information about problems, including how to fix them.

Comment: See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/4154375) and the [When Should You Quote?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F) section of [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: for the final 9-way conditional ... something a bit more compact: `win=false; for tuple in '1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9' 'other six triples'; do read -r i j k <<< "$tuple"; [[ "${bmap[i]}" && "${bmap[j]}" && "${bmap[k]}" ]] && win='true' && break; done; echo "$win"`

Comment: @Barmar,  the bash man page states that "test" value for true is 0 and 1 for false.  Since I believe my bmap assigments are doing that, why can't I work with those ?

Comment: @markp-fuso, thank you for that different approach.  That looks rather elegant.  I think I will incorporate that.

Comment: @pjh, you were correct about the quotes.  I was under the impression that the process RC would be captured ( zero or one ) but that is not being interpreted by the shell the way I conceived it would, so that was critical, but not the only element missing (i.e. the "|| .." part of the testing on each array element.

Comment: "value" is not the same as "output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues with the current design:

- 'capturing' a boolean usually involves an explicit assignment of a 'value'  based on the result of the test (eg, `[ test ] && x='true_value' || x='false_value'`)
- for `${bmap[?]` to evaluate as 'false' it needs to be blank (ie, any non-blank value is treated as 'true')
- if a variable is blank/unset then when testing it is necessary to wrap the variable reference in double quotes to keep from receiving a runtime syntax error (eg, `[[ ${bmap[1]} ]]` should be `[[ "${bmap[1]}" ]]`)

Updating OP's current code to set a 'true' (non-blank) or 'false' (blank) value:

```
for ((i=1;i<=9;i++))
do
    [[ "${board[i]}" == "${symbol}" ]] && bmap[i]=1 || bmap[i]=
    #                                                          ^^ blank == false
    #                                             ^^ non-blank == true
done
```

And the tests become:

```
if \
[[ "${bmap[1]}" && "${bmap[2]}" && "${bmap[3]}" ]] ||
....
```

---

Sample test run:

```
# set all board entries to `X` except for #4 (set to `O`):

$ for ((i=1;i<=9;i++)); do board[i]=X; done
$ board[4]=O

# populate bmap[] based on symbol=X

$ symbol=X
$ for ((i=1;i<=9;i++)); do  [[ "${board[i]}" == "${symbol}" ]] && bmap[i]=1 || bmap[i]=; done

# results:

$ typeset -p board bmap
declare -a board=([1]="X" [2]="X" [3]="X" [4]="O" [5]="X" [6]="X" [7]="X" [8]="X" [9]="X")
                                              ^^^
declare -a  bmap=([1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="1" [4]=""  [5]="1" [6]="1" [7]="1" [8]="1" [9]="1")
                                              ^^
       ##### all bmap[] entries are 'true' (non-blank) except for bmap[4] which is 'false' (blank)

# boolean tests:

$ [[ "${bmap[1]}" ]] && echo 'true'
true

$ [[ "${bmap[4]}" ]] && echo 'true'
         -- no output because bmap[4] is blank (aka 'false')
```

---

**NOTES:**

- from a performance perspective this should be quite a bit faster than the current/new design that spawns 9 sub-processes (`bmap[1-9]=$( test ${board[1-9]} == ${symbol} )`) though ...
- OP may not see much of a performance improvement from the original game design ( `if [[ ${board[1]} == ${symbol} && ${board[2]} == ${symbol}...`)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
bmap=( dummy )
for i in {1..9}; do
    [[ ${board[i]} == "$symbol" ]] && bmap[i]=1 || bmap[i]=0
done
```

One way to use the logical (0 (false) and 1(true)) values in the `bmap` array is:

```
wins=( 1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9   1 4 7   2 5 8   3 6 9   1 5 9   3 5 7 )
result=false
for ((i=0; i<${#wins[*]}; i+=3)); do
    if (( bmap[wins[i]] && bmap[wins[i+1]] && bmap[wins[i+2]] )); then
        result=true
        break
    fi
done
echo "$result"
```

However, it's not clear to me that using the `bmap` array is a significant optimization.

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean implementation of the game tries to optimize by avoiding command substitution (`$(...)`), reducing repetition, and using fewer variables:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

board=( ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' '  ' ' )

function play_game
{
    draw_board

    local player
    for player in X O X O X O X O X; do
        do_move "$player"
        draw_board

        if is_win_for "$player"; then
            printf '*** WINNER is Player %s ***\n' "$player"
            return 0
        fi
    done

    printf '\n*** DRAW - NO WINNER ***\n'
}

function draw_board
{
    printf '
        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | %s | %s | %s |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y | %s | %s | %s |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   | %s | %s | %s |
    +   +---+---+---+\n' "${board[@]:1:9}"
}

function do_move
{
    local -r player=$1

    local x y board_pos
    while :; do
        printf "\\nPlayer %s's turn:\\n" "$player"
        read_coordinate x
        read_coordinate y

        board_pos=$(( x + 3*(y-1) ))
        if [[ ${board[board_pos]} == ' ' ]]; then
            board[board_pos]=$player
            return 0
        else
            printf 'That space is taken.  Please choose another ...\n'
        fi
    done
}

function read_coordinate
{
    while read -r -p "    Enter $1 coordinate [1-3]: " "$1"; do
        if [[ -z ${!1} || ${!1} == *[^0-9]* ]]; then
            printf 'Not a valid number: %q.  Try again.\n' "${!1}" >&2
        elif (( $1 < 1 || $1 > 3)); then
            printf '%d is not in range 1-3.  Try again.\n' "${!1}" >&2
        else
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}

function is_win_for
{
    local -r player=$1

    local -r wins=( 1 2 3   4 5 6   7 8 9       # rows
                    1 4 7   2 5 8   3 6 9       # columns
                    1 5 9   3 5 7           )   # diagonals

     local i j
     for ((i=0; i<${#wins[*]}; i+=3)); do
        for ((j=i; j<(i+3); j++)); do
            [[ ${board[wins[j]]} == "$player" ]] || continue 2
        done

        return 0
    done

    return 1
}

play_game
```

Comment: \@pjh, nicely done!  Thank you for your short-form logic for the **draw_board** function.  Also for the approach using the explicit list of player tokens.  Also, I need to study your logic for **is_win_for** .   That looks very interesting but I have some trouble understanding the "for loop elements ( "i+=3", "continue 2" ).

Answer (score 0):

**Final version of script**, incorporating elements chosen from all feedback.  Thank you all!

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=0
DBGm=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --debug ) DBG=1 ; shift ;;
        --monitor ) DBGm=1 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo -e "\n\t Invalid parameter used on the command line.  Only valid options: [ --debug | --monitor ] \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579778/tictactoe-bash-script

#REVISED:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610032/creating-and-using-bash-array-of-logical-values/75610228#75610228

board=( " "
    " "  " "  " "
        " "  " "  " "
        " "  " "  " " )

bmap=( "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" )


function draw_board() {
    echo -e "\n\t    +-1-+-2-+-3-+"
    echo -e   "\t          X"
    echo -e   "\t+   +---+---+---+"
    echo -e   "\t1   | ${board[1]} | ${board[2]} | ${board[3]} |"
    echo -e   "\t+   +---+---+---+"
    echo -e   "\t2 Y | ${board[4]} | ${board[5]} | ${board[6]} |"
    echo -e   "\t+   +---+---+---+"
    echo -e   "\t3   | ${board[7]} | ${board[8]} | ${board[9]} |"
    echo -e   "\t+   +---+---+---+"
}

function boolean_map() {
    test ${DBGm} -eq 1 && set -x
    local symbol="${1}"

    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t symbol = '${symbol}'"

    test "${board[1]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[1]=1 || bmap[1]=""  ;
    test "${board[2]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[2]=1 || bmap[2]=""  ; 
    test "${board[3]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[3]=1 || bmap[3]=""  ; 
    test "${board[4]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[4]=1 || bmap[4]=""  ; 
    test "${board[5]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[5]=1 || bmap[5]=""  ; 
    test "${board[6]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[6]=1 || bmap[6]=""  ; 
    test "${board[7]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[7]=1 || bmap[7]=""  ; 
    test "${board[8]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[8]=1 || bmap[8]=""  ; 
    test "${board[9]}" == "${symbol}" && bmap[9]=1 || bmap[9]=""  ; 

    test ${DBGm} -eq 1 && set +x

    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && for val in "${!bmap[@]}"
    do
        echo -e "\t\t bmap[${val}] = '${bmap[${val}]}'" >&2
    done
}

function check_win() {
    # REFERENCE:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/133395599?noredirect=1

    ###
    ### IMPORTANT:  Approach used here lends itself very well to much more complex truth table logic
    ###

    win='false'
    for tuple in '1 2 3' '4 5 6' '7 8 9' '1 4 7' '2 5 8' '3 6 9' '1 5 9' '3 5 7'
    do
        read -r i j k <<< "${tuple}"
        test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t\t ${i} = ${bmap[${i}]} " >&2
        test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e   "\t\t ${j} = ${bmap[${j}]} " >&2
        test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e   "\t\t ${k} = ${bmap[${k}]} " >&2
        [[ "${bmap[${i}]}" && "${bmap[${j}]}" && "${bmap[${k}]}" ]] && win="true" && break
    done
    echo "${win}"
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t\t win = ${win}" >&2
}

function is_free() {
    local index=${1}
    if [[ ${board[${index}]} == " " ]]; then
        echo 'true'
    else
        echo 'false'
    fi
}

function game_loop {
    local player="X"
    local move_count=0
    local win=false

    draw_board

    while [[ ${move_count} -lt 9 ]]; do
        #echo "$player következik. Adja meg az x koordinátát [1-3]: "
        echo -e "\nPlayer ${player}'s turn:\n\tEnter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: \c"
        read xVal
            #echo "Adja meg az y koordinátát [1-3]: "
        echo -e "\tEnter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: \c"
        read yVal

        if [[ ${xVal} -lt 1 || ${xVal} -gt 3 || ${yVal} -lt 1 || ${yVal} -gt 3 ]]; then
                    #echo "Hibás koordináta!" >&2
            echo -e "\n\t ERROR:  Invalid coordinate entered!  Please try again ..." >&2
        else
            if [[ $(is_free $(( (yVal-1) * 3 + xVal ))) == true ]]; then
                board[$(( (yVal-1) * 3 + xVal ))]="${player}"
                    ((move_count++))
                
                boolean_map "${player}"

                    win=$(check_win $player)
                    if [[ ${win} == "true" ]]; then
                        draw_board
                            #echo "$player győzött!"
                        echo -e "\n\t\t\t\t*** WINNER is Player ${player} ***"
                    break
                    else
                        if [[ ${player} == "X" ]]; then
                                player="O"
                        else
                                player="X"
                    fi
                fi
            else
                    #echo "Lépéshiba!" >&2
                echo -e "\n\t WARNING:  That space is already taken.  Please try again ..."
            fi
        fi
        draw_board
    done

    if [[ ${win} == "false" ]]; then
            #echo "Dontetlen!"
        echo -e "\n\t\t\t\t*** DRAW - NO WINNER ***"
    fi
}

game_loop
```

**Session output/interaction:**

```
        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

Player X's turn:
    Enter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: 1
    Enter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: 1

        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | X |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

Player O's turn:
    Enter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: 2
    Enter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: 1

        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

Player X's turn:
    Enter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: 1
    Enter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: 2

        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y | X |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

Player O's turn:
    Enter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: 2
    Enter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: 2

        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   |   |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

Player X's turn:
    Enter your choice of x coordinate [1-3]: 1
    Enter your choice of y coordinate [1-3]: 3

        +-1-+-2-+-3-+
              X
    +   +---+---+---+
    1   | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    2 Y | X | O |   |
    +   +---+---+---+
    3   | X |   |   |
    +   +---+---+---+

                *** WINNER is Player X ***
```

Comment: in `boolean_map()` the 9 separate `test && bmap[N] || bmap(N)` lines can be replaced with a looping construct (see my answer); this won't make any difference to performance since you'll still be running 9x test/assignments

Comment: @markp-fuso, thank you.  I was focusing more on the optimization of the tuple tests, not the test of individual contents, to see if there was a way to optimize the process if it were scale up significantly (as I mentionned in one of the comments, for truth-tables of undefined purpose (circuit logic, neural nets, etc.).  Yes, this would not be the language for those applications, but as proof of concept environment, bash is a "goto" for me.

Comment: understood; I toyed, for a few seconds, with how to use 'matrix math' ('karnaugh maps` anyone?) but quickly shelved that idea (in the intervening eons I've forgotten even the basics); for a decent incremental bump up in performance you could look at some rudimentary parallel processing (relatively 'easy' in `bash`) or other languages (I find it much easier to convert `bash` to `awk` ... to an extent)

Comment: For the most part, **awk** has become my workhorse.  I kept this script in bash because the OP of the other posting was doing it in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash regex. 3x3 is pretty simple, it's like 3 arrays with 3 indexes:

```
l1=( '' '' '' )
l2=( '' '' '' )
l3=( '' '' '' )
```

You have to check 8 variants: 3 lines, 3 columns and 2 diagonals. This could be done in single(for each side) regex like this:

```
for side in o x; {
check="$side $side $side"

#    check              all lines              |                                   all columns                                              |                      and two diagonals
[[ "$check" =~ ^${l1[@]}$|^${l2[@]}$|^${l3[@]}$|^${l1[0]}\ ${l2[0]}\ ${l3[0]}$|^${l1[1]}\ ${l2[1]}\ ${l3[1]}$|^${l1[2]}\ ${l2[2]}\ ${l3[2]}$|^${l1[0]}\ ${l2[1]}\ ${l3[2]}$|^${l1[2]}\ ${l2[1]}\ ${l3[0]}$ ]] && echo $side wins
}
```

Columns and diagonals could be preset-ted for better view:

```
l1=( '' '' '' )
l2=( '' '' '' )
l3=( '' '' '' )
c1=( "${l1[0]}" "${l2[0]}" "${l3[0]}" )
c2=( "${l1[1]}" "${l2[1]}" "${l3[1]}" )
c3=( "${l1[2]}" "${l2[2]}" "${l3[2]}" )
d1=( "${l1[0]}" "${l2[1]}" "${l3[2]}" )
d2=( "${l1[2]}" "${l2[1]}" "${l3[0]}" )

for side in o x; {
check="$side $side $side"

#    check                all lines            |          all columns           | and two diagonals
[[ "$check" =~ ^${l1[@]}$|^${l2[@]}$|^${l3[@]}$|^${c1[@]}$|^${c2[@]}$|^${c3[@]}$|^${d1[@]}$|^${d2[@]}$ ]] && echo $side wins
}
```